# Can someone explain to me how volatility/premium works for ATM swaptions? Why are they the same for calls and puts?

Tags: swaption

I don't understand how Bloomberg quotes ATM swaptions, they just show the same volatility/premium and don't separate calls and puts. Are they the same? How does it tie to normal volatility? Thanks

Comment: Also https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/71555/54838. Atm premium quoted is usually a straddle. Bloomberg has a help desk which would answer these type of questions swiftly (F1 F1). Or you look at the DES page of the ticker.

Comment: If the premium is quoted as straddle, is there a way to separate call and put prices?

Comment: Of course. Strike is ATM, which means you back out vol and compute call and put. The linked answer essentially explains this, as well as what normal vol or black vol is.